# Firebase Database connection with Java server throws `InvocationTargetException`

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect to firebase database from my Java Server. When i get any reference from `FirebaseDatabase` object, it throws `InvocationTargetException`

Error log trace :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.GaePlatform.getGaeThreadFactory(GaePlatform.java:67)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.GaePlatform.isActive(GaePlatform.java:78)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.getPlatform(Context.java:42)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.ensureLogger(Context.java:211)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.initServices(Context.java:77)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.freeze(Context.java:64)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createLocalRepo(RepoManager.java:78)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createRepo(RepoManager.java:28)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.ensureRepo(FirebaseDatabase.java:249)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(FirebaseDatabase.java:125)
    at com.hw.service.impl.AppServiceImpl.repopulateCounsellors(AppServiceImpl.java:161)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.repopulateCounsellors(Unknown Source)
    at com.hw.controller.AppController.repopulateCounsellors(AppController.java:70)
```

Nested exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.GaePlatform.getGaeThreadFactory(GaePlatform.java:62)
... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager.backgroundThreadFactory(ThreadManager.java:72)
```

Error occurs here in the 3rd line of the code below `fireDB.getReference`

```
FirebaseDatabase fireDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp);
System.out.println(fireDB);
DatabaseReference ref = fireDB.getReference("/users");
System.out.println("db counsellor ref : " + ref);
System.out.println("db ref key : " + ref.getKey());
```

I am using Spring MVC for my java Server. `firebaseApp` is autowired and initialized in config class as :

```
        String firebaseJson = env.getProperty("firebase.credentials");
        String fireDb = env.getProperty("firebase.db");
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream(firebaseJson))
                .setDatabaseUrl(fireDb)
                .build();
        return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

I have no idea where i am going wrong

Comment: An InvocationTargetException should have a nested exception.  Show us the stacktrace for that as well.

Comment: added nested exception logs ^

Comment: I'm having the same problem trying to write integration tests for my GAE firebase client. It seems like a bug - Firebase crashes when looking to check if GAE is active but when it does that it seems to try to get the GAE Thread Factory and probably crashes.

Pretty disappointing that Firebase engineers have not responded in almost 3 months.

Comment: I am having similar issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/NTaj11UYAuk

Comment: Same issue, anyone resolve this?